# Unable to load SQLite extension from other folder

Tags: windows, sqlite, dll, module

#### Brief

I compiled SQLite extension to dll file and I am able to load it by loading `rot13.dll` from the same directory, but I cannot load it if it's in any other directory (even same directory, but with relative path).

#### Details

I'm using Windows 10 & Mingw compiler (8.1.0, 64 bit). I have `sqlite3.exe` downloaded from sqlite.org. I've compiled a sample extension `rot13.c`:

```
PS C:\temp\b> gcc -g -fPIC -shared rot13.c -o rot13.dll
```

Here's what I have in this directory:

```
PS C:\temp\b> dir


    Directory: C:\temp\b


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        15.02.2021     13:54           2887 rot13.c
-a----        15.02.2021     15:46          68958 rot13.dll
------        20.01.2021     15:38        8182289 sqlite3.c
------        20.01.2021     15:40         994816 sqlite3.exe
------        20.01.2021     15:38         583202 sqlite3.h
------        20.01.2021     15:38          35437 sqlite3ext.h
```

Now, I run the sqlite3 client and attempt to load the extension using just a file name:

```
PS C:\temp\b> sqlite3
SQLite version 3.34.1 2021-01-20 14:10:07
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.

sqlite> select load_extension('rot13.dll');

sqlite> select rot13('xyz');
klm
```

Works as expected. Now let's try with "current directory" path (it's a new instance of the sqlite3.exe running, I just skept sqlite3 startup message):

```
sqlite> select load_extension('./rot13.dll');

sqlite> select rot13('xyz');
klm
```

So far, so good. Now, the interesting part:

```
sqlite> select load_extension('../b/rot13.dll');
Error: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.

sqlite> select load_extension('c:/temp/b/rot13.dll');
Error: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.

sqlite> select load_extension('c:\temp\b\rot13.dll');
Error: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.

sqlite> select load_extension('/temp/b/rot13.dll');
Error: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.

sqlite> select load_extension('\temp\b\rot13.dll');
Error: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.
```

It says in polish *"Cannot find the specified module"*.

The problem appears to affect any relative or absolute path. The biggest mistake to me is that it works if it's just a file name, not a (relative/absolute) path, so it's not because of incorrectly compiled extension, or missing dependencies. At least that's how I understand it.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: As a workaround you could add *c:\\temp\\b* to *PATH* and just use base filename.

Answer (score 0):

Just a moments after posting question, I found the answer. I will post it as well, so maybe it will help someone.

The answer is simple - I had another `rot13.dll` elsewhere in the system (but also in the `PATH`). The `sqlite3.exe` was from sqlite.org, which I believe is compiled with VC++, whereas I compiled `C:\temp\b\rot13.dll` with mingw (and I guess that the other rot13.dll was compiled with VC++). After the `sqlite3.exe` failed to load exactly `C:\temp\b\rot13.dll`, it proceeded with attempt to load other combinations and find found the one in `PATH`.

After compiling my own `sqlite3.exe` with mingw I'm able to load `rot13.dll` compiled with mingw too - the one which I had problems before. All relative/absolute/file paths work now.